# javascript get variable open in new window

Tags: php, javascript

I have standard text links which all say "Full View". When clicked these links send out php in this form: http://mysite.com/fullview.php?myimage=30

Basically there's thumbnailed images and text links that say full view. I'd like for fullview.php to capture the myimage variable, and display it as a full sized image. Meaning, a blank page (fullview.php) displaying the image. Sounds likes javascript to me.

How do you put the javascript into fullview.php to capture the variable and display it as a full sized image?

myimage=30 can be any number example: myimage=942

Thanks for any help, Darrell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to display a full-sized view of images, you may consider using a JavaScript image display library, such as [fancybox](http://fancybox.net/). You can probably achieve what you want with the `autoDimensions: true` option, which is the default.

Comment: Did'nt use this, but it will work. I just got rid of the text links, and linked off of the thumbnails to open in a new window. Thanks bro, fancybox is a nice program, I looked at it for several hours, and it's sweet!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are passing image id(`myimage=30`) to `fullview.php`. So you can simply get it with `$_GET['myimage']` in `fullview.php`. Now you can use this `imageid` to get image and just display it with HTML `<img>` tag.

For example in **fullview.php**

```
if( isset( $_GET['myimage'] ) ) {
   $imageid = $_GET['myimage'];
   echo "<img src='/images/folder/path/" . $imageid . ".jpg' />";
}
```

Comment: I've had other people tell me the same thing, but it will not work. I've tried it. Needs javascript. Client side vs. Server side issue.

Comment: You are calling `fullview.php`. It means you are calling server side script. So on server side you have to deal it with server side language. No matter how are you calling `fullview.php`, with html link or JavaScript onclick event.

Comment: Seems like it might work. Imagine 40,000 images in 86 different folders. Would javascript handle this better?

Comment: It depends that how you are getting images using `myimage` id in `fillview.php`. I think you use this id to get image from database. So php is required to fetch image path/name from database. After that, If you simply want to display image on webpage then you can simply display it using html `img` tag without javascript. But if you want to style it or want to show it in popups then you can use any javascript library..

Comment: Will look into it. Pictures are on the server, but values most likely come from database.